# How to export _all_ nodes and all relations from Neo4j into Gephi?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gephi, neo4j-apoc

I intend to export my entire graph (both nodes with relations and "independent" nodes) into Gephi. In order to achieve it, I currenly execute two queries:

```
// export relationships
match path = (n)--() 
with collect(path) as paths
call apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace1', paths, '', ['attr1', 'attr2']) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time

// export independent nodes
match path = (p) 
where not (p)--()
with collect(path) as paths
call apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace1', paths, '', ['attr1', 'attr2']) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

I have tried to replace them with a single query like:

```
match path = (n)-[*0..]-() 
with collect(path) as paths
call apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace1', paths, '', ['attr1', 'attr2']) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

Unfortunately the query never finishes and effectively DoS-es Neo4j (results in high CPU and RAM consumption on Neo4j side and makes it unresponsive).
I have also tried to limit the relations depth with `[*0..10]` but it didn't help.

What would be a correct way to export my data with a single query?

Comment: If you can shut down your neo4j instance and have access to graph folder, you can use [neo4j-admin](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try in your case the following...

```
match path = (n)-[*0..1]->() 
with collect(path) as paths
call apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace1', paths, '', ['attr1', 'attr2']) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

So we have added the direction of relationships and limit to only 1 hop. This way we remove exporting duplicates and speed up export.